# Classic ASP GoDaddy Plesk How to bind my domain name with login.asp

Tags: asp-classic, plesk, godaddy-api

I do not know how to launch my website at GoDaddy using Plesk. I have uploaded my files to all root directory. At IIS Settings,I have added `login.asp` to the default documents and move up the order.

[image: Root directory]

Now when I click `Preview`

[image: Clicking Preview]

I get the following site and Default.aspx loads

[image: Default.aspx]

If I add login.asp at the back of the URL, my login.asp page loads  **Ignore the error**

[image]

**But** if I click on `Open` at Plesk, I get error

[image: Error is if click Open at Plesk]

**Now how to I bind www.mydomain.com to login.asp?**

Comment: Have you registered your domain name? If yes, please make sure you point your domain to Godaddy name server, please ping your domain if it has pointed to correct IP address.

Comment: yes I have, the domain name is hansmidco.com

Comment: there must be some tweak to point the folder to this domain name?

Comment: Where did you register this domain name? On Godaddy? If yes, you just need to contact their support team to check it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called the support and they will fix it.